# Update password devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have `update_without_password` method to my form but I would know how update my password in my `edit_user_registration_path`.

I realized that I cant change my password if I do not give my current password,
Can I change the password in my edit_user_form even with `update_wothout_password` method ?

My registration controller :

```
def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_without_password(params)
  end

  def after_update_path_for(resource)
      biens_path(resource)
  end
```

Comment: is `update_without_password` method not working?

Comment: can you be express clearly on problem statement?

Comment: The update_without_password work but if add it i cant change my password because to change the password i need the current password field i would know a method to change the password in edit registration  path without be force to give the current password @Nithin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I have my user set up in most of my apps

In the model I have a method that should_validate_password?

```
# app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :updating_password
  ...
  def should_validate_password?
    updating_password || new_record?
  end
  ...
end
```

Now in the controller I have a before filter

```
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb 
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_password_submitted, :only => :update
  ...
  private
  def check_password_submitted
    if params[:user][:password].blank?
      params[:user].delete("password")
      params[:user].delete("password_confirmation")
      user.updating_password = false
    else
      user.updating_password = true
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

and this is what works for me

Comment: Thanks for your help, you keep the "update_without_password" method ?

Comment: There is no need when the form is submitted the controller checks if there is a password or not and then updates the models `updating_password` method